# Unit test: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, enzyme

I know " Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." has been asked many times, but I can't find the solution.

The problem only happens in the enzyme test.

This is my componentDidMount, which logs the response:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```

log response: users: (27) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
type: "GET_USERS_SUCCESS"

And this is my action

```
export const fetchUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchUSersRequest())
  const request = axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${BASE_URL}users.json`,
    headers: []
  })
  return request.then(
    response => dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(response.data)),
    err => dispatch(fetchUsersError(err))
  )
}
```

The component is a connected component. and here it's test

```
import React from 'react'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import Users from './'
import * as mocks from '../../mocks/users'

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe('it works', () => {
  const store = mockStore({});
  const wrapper = shallow(<Users store={store} users={mocks.getUsersMock} filters={mocks.getFiltersMock} />).dive().dive()
  console.log(wrapper.debug())
  it("renders a div", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('div').length).toBe(1)
  })
});
```

Then the error is in the unit test output

● it works › encountered a declaration exception

```
Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

  21 |
  22 |   componentDidMount () {
> 23 |     this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())
     |                ^
  24 |   }
```

I am already using redux-thunk

Comment: this question saves me!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try registering `redux-thunk` middleware with your `redux-mock-store` so that the tests are aware of the async middleware you are using in your actual store is using:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Oh! thank you very much! That worked, I've spent hours with this...What a relief :)

Comment: your the hero that I didn't ask for, but deffiently the hero I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Hours reading other threads about redux... this solves everyhing

Comment: Should this go in my `App.test.tsx` file (i.e., the top most level)?

Comment: @tim.rohrer you may want to make this an exported function so that you can create instances of this mock store and pass to your component that takes a store. Do you have a test root component that takes a store that wraps test elements? It really depends on the testing you are doing.

Comment: I wouldn't say I have a "test" root component. My understanding is that I need to provide this wrapper in each component that tries to touch the store...if that isn't correct, then perhaps I need to open a new question, or find something else to read :-)

Comment: Yes, connected components would need to be wrapped with some component with a mock store. You can create that mock store in any file, including the test file you are currently working in. I’d recommend to make a function that creates a mock store that you can reuse in multiple test files. If that’s not clear you may want to make a question with the specific issue you are experiencing.